# Appropriate way to set a duration in Java

Tags: java, datetime, types, duration

What is the appropriate way to set a duration in Java with **standard** Java libs? Date()? Calendar()? Example?

Thanks & Cheers
ER

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a de-facto standard for Java Date & time - JodaTime. It has [`Duration`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html). The JodaTime API is considered far better than `Date` and `Calendar`.

Of course, you can also store the duration in a `long` - the milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about Joda, however, I would like to know how a duration would be represented with standard libraries ...

Comment: O ... that "long" is what I like much more. I just want to make sure that this would be best practice with standard libs. long, or even int, would be great!

Comment: Don’t use `long`. Sooner or later someone will be in doubt whether they are seconds or milliseconds or something else and will waste time finding out. Also these days don’t use Joda-Time for new code, it’s outdated. Do use `java.time.Duration`. See the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Java-8 standard library

[`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html).

**A quick demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Duration.ofNanos(1234567890));
        System.out.println(Duration.ofMillis(123456789));
        System.out.println(Duration.ofSeconds(12345678));
        System.out.println(Duration.ofMinutes(1234567));
        System.out.println(Duration.ofHours(123456));
        System.out.println(Duration.ofDays(12345));

        System.out.println(Duration.between(LocalTime.of(1, 2, 3), LocalTime.of(4, 5, 6)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT1.23456789S
PT34H17M36.789S
PT3429H21M18S
PT20576H7M
PT123456H
PT296280H
PT3H3M3S
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.